# Java add string value numbers into dynamic arraylist, in the right order

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, addition

I have an arraylist of `Objects` where i am pulling them in Java from a Sparql Query placing them into an `arraylist` with `while(result.hasNext())`.

The problem is that i have to take the results based on their `URI` from the query. So `Object1` comes first, then comes 10,11 etc and after all comes `Object2`.

I want the Objects to be placed in order inside the arraylist `(1,2,...,10,11..).` I have tried to sort the `arraylist` based on some property and i want to avoid counting the Objects and then make the `arraylist` the same count of Objects and use `add(index, Object)`.

Is there a way to do it without knowing the size of the arraylist?

Thank You.

Comment: Why are you using an ArrayList, can you use another type of Collection?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Why do you want to use `add(index, Object)`. The ArrayList has a dynamic size. It will resize automatically for you.

Comment: Could you add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query?

Answer (score 0):

implement `equals()` method in your class which present in arrylist and then use `Collections.sort()` to sort your array list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Collections.sort(List, Comperator)` method.

Just add all results from your query to the List and sort it with a given Comperator. In this comperator you have to implement the `compare()` method to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you need. You don't need to use a Comparator:

```
String s = uri.toString();
//trim your string to return only the Object index.
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
list.add(i, Object);
```

or you could use a Map and retrieve the Objects by URI

```
Map<URI, Object> = new HashMap<>();
map.put(URI, Object);
```